# Rational points on conics over fields of dimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, algebraic-curves, algebraic-k-theory

Let $K$ be a field of cohomological dimension 1 and $C$ be a smooth projective conic over $K$. Is it true that $C$ always has a $K$-point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Every such conic is a [Severi-Brauer variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severi%E2%80%93Brauer_variety), so is classified by an element of the Brauer group $H^2(K, \mathbb{G}_m)$, which vanishes by hypothesis. The trivial element of the Brauer group corresponds to the Severi-Brauer variety $\mathbb{P}^1$, which in turn corresponds to the original Severi-Brauer variety having a rational point.

Note that if $K$ is a finite field you can argue more directly using the [Chevalley-Warning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem).